# Entity Framework CodeFirst create relationship between 2 table on non primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Hello I am trying to add a migration and change the primary key of the table not to primary key as this has just become a requirement. Now that said it will always be unique, but needs to have a one to many relationship. with other tables and cascade on update.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963793/entity-framework-6-1-3-foreign-key-on-non-primary-key-field) but this isn't using DataAnnotations which i am, and want to contenue to do so.

Here are the 2 classes in question.

```
public partial class MProcurement
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MProcurement()
    {
        Logs = new List<MLog>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(8)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string ParcelId { get; set; } //current primary key that i want to change
    [Required]
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string ProducerCode { get; set; }
    public FscCertType FscCertType { get; set; }
    public int CountyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public Scale  ProducerScale { get; set; }
    public Scale Scale { get; set; }
    public Terms Terms { get; set; }
    public bool UseProducerScale { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public virtual MUser User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProducerCode))]
    public virtual MProducer Producer { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CountyId))]
    public virtual MCounty County { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual List<MLog> Logs { get; set; }
}


public partial class MLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Tag { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(8), MaxLength(8)]
    [Index("IX_Proc_Seq", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(MProcurement.ParcelId))]//would like to add to MProcurement as ForignKey
    public string ProcurementId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

    public Scale Scale { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_Proc_Seq",2,IsUnique = true)]
    public int Seq { get; set; }

    public bool DoubleLength { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(4)]
    public string SpecieId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(1)]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Length { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CutbackLength { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CutbackFeet { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Diameter { get; set; }
    public int? Pounds { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Feet { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal NetCost { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal AdjCostPerFoot { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal AdjustedNet { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal ProducerPricePerFoot { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal CostPerFoot { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ProducerFeet { get; set; }

    public virtual MCategory Category { get; set; }
    public virtual MSpecie Specie { get; set; }


    public virtual MProcurement Procurement { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Not possible in EF6 but EF Core will support it. I would reconsider fluent - it separates your concerns and there are some things you can't do with annotations. https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support

Comment: I have alot of work into annotations, is it much to to change over to Fluent?

Comment: If you have a lot of them, you could use the reverse engineering tool which will give you the equivalent fluent code. You could also selectively use them when needed. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/11/28/composing-entity-framework-fluent-configurations.aspx